# portlet.getInstanceId() alway return null in JSP of portlet hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I use liferay 6.2.

I want to get a instance id of portlet in file jsp of portlet hook. Bellow is my code, but instance id alway print `null` to console:

```
<% 
List<Portlet> portletList = null;
try{
    portletList =PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortlets();
}catch(Exception e){}
for(Portlet portlet : portletList){
    String portletName = portlet.getDisplayName();
    if(portletName.equals("Asset Categories Navigation")) {
        System.out.println("Portlet instance Id >>> " + portlet.getInstanceId());
        System.out.println("Portlet Display Name >>> " + portletName); 
        System.out.println("Portlet Id >>> " + portlet.getPortletId());
        System.out.println("Portlet Name >>> " + portlet.getPortletName()); 
        break;
    }
}
%>
```

Output:

```
Portlet instance Id >>> null
Portlet Display Name >>> Asset Categories Navigation
Portlet Id >>> 122
Portlet Name >>> 122
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that API correctly (from its methods) it will provide you with all the portlets that you can instantiate and add to the page, but not the actually instantiated portlets.

In order to get the instantiated portlets, you'd typically come through the page (Layout in the API) and inspect what's added there.

On a portal with thousands of pages, each with multiple portlets, it wouldn't make sense to blindly enumerate *all* of the instantiated portlets, plus, they're not referenced through the portlet, but only through the pages (because that's how they're commonly accessed).

A portlet that's not instantiated on a page naturally has no instance id. You should be able to check it by taking any portlet, for example the "Asset Categories Navigation", and drop it on multiple pages. I'd predict that your code would result in exactly one occurrence of that portlet.